# Use INSERT within CASE statement in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, insert, case

I'm using MSSQL. Below is my sql code

```
DECLARE @CoursesAboutToExpire TABLE (CourseID   BIGINT, ExpiryDate  DATE, IsApplicableToAllInternalUser BIT)

INSERT INTO @CoursesAboutToExpire
    SELECT CourseID, ExpiryDate, IsApplicableToAllInternalUser
    FROM CMS_CoursesMaster CM

DECLARE @ApplicableUsersWithCourse TABLE (UserID    BIGINT, CourseID    BIGINT)


SELECT 1 ,
    (CASE WHEN CAE.IsApplicableToAllInternalUser = 1
        THEN (INSERT INTO @ApplicableUsersWithCourse SELECT UM.UserID, CAE.CourseID FROM TRC_UserMaster UM)
        ELSE (INSERT INTO @ApplicableUsersWithCourse SELECT CAP.UserID, CAP.CourseID FROM CMS_CourseApplicabilityParameters CAP WHERE CAP.CourseID=CAE.CourseID)
    ) AS 2
FROM @CoursesAboutToExpire CAE
```

I'm trying to insert records on the basis *IsApplicableToAllInternalUser * column value using `case` statement. but it gives error.

Comment: A case *expression* returns an atomic value, it cannot be used to control program flow.

Comment: Well, first issue is that you are trying to insert three values on a table with only two columns. Fix that first. Then, you can do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` for inserting into your `@ApplicableUsersWithCourse`, selecting only the ones that have the `IsApplicableToAllInternalUser = 1` from `@CoursesAboutToExpire`.

Comment: @RigertaDemiri  Thanks for the update. I have to INSERT rows from different table depending on 'IsApplicableToAllInternalUser'. If 'IsApplicableToAllInternalUser=1' then i want all records from UserMaster table, else I want records from CMS_CourseApplicabilityParameters table.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can just replace the CASE statement you are trying to execute, with the following `INSERT INTO .. SELECT` statements:

```
DECLARE @ApplicableUsersWithCourse TABLE (UserID    BIGINT, CourseID    BIGINT)

INSERT INTO @ApplicableUsersWithCourse 
SELECT UM.UserID, CAE.CourseID 
FROM TRC_UserMaster UM JOIN @CoursesAboutToExpire CAE ON UM.CourseID = CAE.CourseID 
WHERE CAE.IsApplicableToAllInternalUser = 1

INSERT INTO @ApplicableUsersWithCourse 
SELECT CAP.UserID, CAP.CourseID 
FROM CMS_CourseApplicabilityParameters CAP JOIN @CoursesAboutToExpire CAE ON CAP.CourseID=CAE.CourseID
WHERE CAE.IsApplicableToAllInternalUser = 0
```

You can initially test the records you are going to insert by just executing the `SELECT` statements first. If it looks OK, you can insert the records.

This can also be written as follows:

```
INSERT INTO @ApplicableUsersWithCourse 

SELECT UM.UserID, CAE.CourseID 
FROM TRC_UserMaster UM JOIN @CoursesAboutToExpire CAE ON UM.CourseID = CAE.CourseID 
WHERE CAE.IsApplicableToAllInternalUser = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT CAP.UserID, CAP.CourseID 
FROM CMS_CourseApplicabilityParameters CAP JOIN @CoursesAboutToExpire CAE ON CAP.CourseID=CAE.CourseID
WHERE CAE.IsApplicableToAllInternalUser = 0
```

Comment: thanks guys for your help. but none of above worked for me. `cross join` did it. @Rigerta The Join of `UserMaster` & `@CoursesAboutToExpire` is not applicable, as Usermaster did not have `CourseId` column. After trying many of experiments and headache, finally `cross join` came for help. See Answer for code that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me.

```
 DECLARE @CoursesAboutToExpire TABLE (CourseID   BIGINT, ExpiryDate  DATE, IsApplicableToAllInternalUser BIT)
```

`INSERT INTO @CoursesAboutToExpire 
      SELECT CourseID, ExpiryDate, IsApplicableToAllInternalUser FROM CMS_CoursesMaster CM`

`DECLARE @ApplicableUsersWithCourse TABLE (UserID    BIGINT, CourseID    BIGINT)`

`INSERT INTO @ApplicableUsersWithCourse 
       SELECT UM.UserID, CAE.CourseID FROM TRC_UserMaster UM 
          CROSS JOIN @CoursesAboutToExpire CAE 
      WHERE CAE.IsApplicableToAllInternalUser = 1)`

`INSERT INTO @ApplicableUsersWithCourse 
       SELECT CAP.UserID, CAP.CourseID FROM CMS_CourseApplicabilityParameters CAP 
          INNER JOIN @CoursesAboutToExpire CAE ON CAP.CourseID=CAE.CourseID 
       WHERE CAE.IsApplicableToAllInternalUser = 0`